# Solve does not find solutions to large equation rotation matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, vector

I've been seeing some posts already where people mention Solve needs a bit of help to get things solved in some scenarios.
I have been trying to figure out the solutions for equations. For the XYZ position, I get the exact equation written by hand. For the rotation matrix, I generated it in Mathematica.

In the code below you'll find that I have the expected tip coordinates. Also, I define the original vectors of this tip before any rotations. To get from the rotated (transformed) vectors, just multiply the Matrix by the original Vector.

In the solving, I define equations to obtain x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 which are the angles in radians.

This code below won't finish Solving, giving an empty solution output. I get a warning that tells me "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. Try Reduce or FindInstance instead.". I am not sure if there is a better approximation for this.

There are solutions for sure. To prove it you can find below the code that generates XYZ coordinates and Transformed Vectors based on known angles. However when applying those to the main code "Solve" will find no solutions.

CODE:

```
Tip = {200, 300, 100};
Target = {-1000, 0, 200};
VectorTipTarget = Target - Tip;

(* Estas son las orientaciones de mis vectores originales *)
vector1Original = {0, -1, 0};
vector2Original = {-1, 0, 0};
vector3Original = {0, 0, -1};

(* Estos son los vectores deseados después de aplicar la matriz de rotación *)
vector1Transformed = Normalize[VectorTipTarget];
vector2Transformed = 
  Normalize[
   Cross[{vector1Transformed[[1]], vector1Transformed[[2]], 0}, 
    vector1Transformed]];
vector3Transformed = 
  Normalize[Cross[vector1Transformed, vector2Transformed]];

(* XYZ equations *)
eqXTip = (280*Cos[x1]*Sin[-x2] + 225*Cos[x1]*Sin[-(x3 + x2)] + 
    118*Sin[x1] + 120*Cos[x1]*Sin[-(x4 + x3 + x2)] + 
    88*(Cos[x1]*Cos[-(x4 + x3 + x2)]*Sin[x5] + Sin[x1]*Cos[x5]));
eqYTip = (280*Sin[x1]*Sin[-x2] + 225*Sin[x1]*Sin[-(x3 + x2)] - 
    118*Cos[x1] + 120*Sin[x1]*Sin[-(x4 + x3 + x2)] + 
    88*(Sin[x1]*Cos[-(x4 + x3 + x2)]*Sin[x5] - Cos[x1]*Cos[x5]));
eqZTip = (223 + 280*Cos[-x2] + 225*Cos[-(x3 + x2)] + 
    120*Cos[-(x4 + x3 + x2)] - 88*Sin[-(x4 + x3 + x2)]*Sin[x5]);

(* Rotation matrix *)
Ry[x_] := RotationMatrix[x, {0, 1, 0}];
Rz[x_] := RotationMatrix[x, {0, 0, 1}];
Matrix = Rz[x1] . Ry[-x2] . Ry[-x3] . Ry[-x4] . Rz[x5] . Ry[x6];

(* Matrix dot Vector original gives equations that depend on x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 *)
eqVectorTransformed1 = FullSimplify[Matrix . vector1Original];
eqVectorTransformed2 = FullSimplify[Matrix . vector2Original];
eqVectorTransformed3 = FullSimplify[Matrix . vector3Original];

(* Solving *)
sol = {};
sol = Solve[{eqXTip == 0, eqYTip == 0, eqZTip == 0, 
   eqVectorTransformed1 == vector1Transformed, 
   eqVectorTransformed2 == vector2Transformed, 
   eqVectorTransformed3 == vector3Transformed}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, 
  Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 5];

Print[sol];
```

Thanks in advance, I think there should be solutions there

Comment: Dont use integer coordinate. You are pressing Solve to return algebraic formulas of exact roots. This ends with polynomials of degree 4.  Inverse adds fractions of multinomials. With trigonometric functions, its hopeless.  Try to work with real numbers by ...//N  after each numerical Set.

Comment: Are you certain there are real-valued solutions? Preliminary attempts with `NSolve` on a modified version are not showing any such.

Comment: I do not understand your code. However, if you try to find the rotation matrix that rotates a vector a into a vector b, there is `RotationMatrix[a,b]`

Comment: @RolandF Thank to you as well. I have rethought the program and thought the following. I know vectorAOriginal and know vectorATransformed. I need to know which angles have been used in the rotation matrix to transform one into the other. No need of the inverse of it, will update the code with a better aproximation
I want to know which angles are needed to rotate the vector from vectorAOriginal to vectorATransformed. So I did the inverse of the matrix, multiplied it by vectorATransformed to obtain vectorA original. However

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think you're right, partially. I have thought I should remove J6 from the rotation matrix. This J6 by itself can cancel the rotation of previous joints, basically J2+J3+J4=-J6, so there were an infinite amount of solutions in this system. I did update the code on the main post.

Comment: It seems you now have more equations than variables, so an overdetermined system. Is that expected?

Comment: Omitting three `FullSimplify` and replacing `Solve` by `NSolve`, I obtain "NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It wasn't :') . It is corrected and checked the rotation matrix is indeed correct now. I had issues with the sign of it.
Now I do obtain "This system cannot be solved with the methods available" as user64494 says. I am trying to Reduce or FindInstance with no luck

Comment: I still see too many equations. The last three are vector equations that each contribute 3 ordinary equations, so a total of 1+1+1+3+3+3=12 equations. But only 6 variables.

Comment: On the up side, the revised system, while overdetermined, does seem to have at least one viable solution. I found it using `FindMinimum on a sum of squares formed from the equations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks, your FindMinimum was key to help me on this and continue with it!